# How can I call an inline script in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-api, content-security-policy

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that will call a Google API, and I was following the tutorial at https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md. However, I noticed that I can't use the script from https://apis.google.com/js/api.js because the CSP won't allow it. I tried changing the CSP, but when I changed it to allow 'unsafe-inline' Chrome wouldn't let me load the extension. I also tried copying the script and putting it into a local copy, but that script seems to call another inline script which triggers CSP again. I'm not really sure where it calls the other script so I can't copy that script into my project. How can I fix this?

The code causing the error is in the second link, and it throws an error on line 20 saying that it violates CSP's guidelines for script-src. This is the error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.lb.en.dzXZWX9QTbE.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AHpOoo_epIQDPHdjFr3MLkazUi2Jmy50dQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why would you change it to `unsafe-inline`? Change it to something containing `apis.google.com`

Comment: I tried both, but chrome doesn't allow either because when I try to load the extension it says it's an insecure CSP value, and the CSP rules for manifest v3 state that the only allowed values for script-src, object-src, and worker-src are self, none, and localhost.